# how to make the map thicker? (gmaping params)

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using the `gmapping/slam_gmapping`  node to create the map using `ros_arduino_bridge` and `neato_laser_driver` with those the `/odom , /scan, and /tf` can be published.

I referred the parameter configuration of rbx1: [here](https://github.com/pirobot/rbx1/blob/indigo-devel/rbx1_nav/launch/gmapping.launch) and I found that:

- **the map is drawn lightly**.
- **there are many emissive lines** which is not as the reality and should be get rid of.

Can you guys tell me which parameter of `slam_gmapping` influences these features?

**Thank You Very Much!!**

ps: I'm using the *ros-indigo* and *neato_xv11* laser scanner. THX!!

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247119/how-to-make-the-map-thicker?-(gmaping-params)/) by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2016-11-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on 2016-11-03**:
The map did not get denser even I stay the robot at some position for 1 hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The emissive lines typically come from laser scanner max range measurements. Some laser scanners map scan errors to max range as well, which could lead to this problem. I haven't worked with the neato myself, so I cannot tell if this is the problem here.

Also, typically, you don't update the map if you don't move the robot. `gmapping` has three parameters when to trigger an update:

1. `linearUpdate`
2. `angularUpdate`
3. `temporalUpdate`

If you want to update also why standing still, you should set `temporalUpdate` to something else then `-1.0` (default), which disables temporal updates.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on 2016-11-17**:
thx mig! I think this problem may be not as so simple. If the map scan errors caused the emissive lines, there should be some black points appears at the end of the emissive lines, more or less. Neverthless, there is no black poit at all.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I changed the `maxRange` parameter and it works well.
emissive lines doesn't appears.

---

Originally posted by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) with karma: 287 on 2016-11-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1